# Sending a Hashtable to a Webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, dictionary, web-services

Im trying to send a List of Items with generic Keys and Value Types to a asp.net webservice.
How can i do this?
I tried it with `List<Dictionary<String, String>>`, but this doens't work. I do not get an exception, but when i break in the webserivice, my collection is null.
The Data could look like this: 
`{"Data":{"fieldtype":"integer","isrequired":true,"isrequirederror":"Invalid Data"}}.` 
But as i said, the Keys are generic, sometimes there are more properties, sometimes not.

Thx alot

This post couldn't help my btw:
[How to send a hashtable to an asmx webservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862271/how-to-send-a-hashtable-to-an-asmx-webservice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have hard times with SOA and WCF in particular if you want to introduce any kind of generics in your service - starting from serialization/deserialization issues and finishing interoperability issues.

Don't use generic parameters. Hashtable (or Dictionary) makes sense only within in-process usage due to read/write operations performance. If you want to transmit something in such format over the wire, use something like the following structure:
**List of pairs (string, string).**

Answer (score 1):

Classes that implement `IDictionary` can't be serialized to XML, it's a limitation of the `XmlSerializer` class. The usual workaround for that it to implement `IXmlSerializable` to provide custom serialization logic, as [shown here](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx). Another option is to transform your dictionary into a list of key/value pairs

Comment: The solution with IXmlSerializable doesn't work for me, can you explain the other solution?

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work" ? what exactly did you do ?

Comment: How would i have to do it? I added the class and Updated my Wevservice Method.
Anyhow...i think i have to convert all values to a string

Comment: declare your object as a `SerializableDictionary<string, SerializableDictionary>` instead of `Dictionary<string, Dictionary>`

Comment: i get this exception: 
Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.String\u0027 to type \u0027SerializableDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]\u0027","StackTrace":"

Comment: You don't give enough information to allow us to help you... show us some code !

Answer (score 0):

```
{"Data":
 {"fieldtype":"integer",
  "isrequired":true,
  "isrequirederror":"Invalid Data"
 }
}
```

: this is not a `List<Dictionary<String, String>>`
it's a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<String, String>>`
could this help?

Comment: Now i get this exception: 
{"Message":"Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.String\u0027 to type \u0027System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]\u0027","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization