# Sending back a hashtable inside a dictionary in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, dictionary, hashtable

I'm trying to send a class via WCF over basicHttpBinding that contains a `Dictionary<byte, object>` and inside it is a `Hashtable` - this is needed due to existing code requirements and it can not be changed.

Now if I send out a class with just a `Dictionary<byte, object>` or `Hashtable` it works like a charm, but when I send out a dictionary containing a Hashtable I get the following error message:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter 
>   http://tempuri.org/:UpdateResult. The InnerException message was 'Type
>   'System.Collections.Hashtable' with data contract name
>   'ArrayOfKeyValueOfanyTypeanyType:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any
>   types not known statically to the list of known types - for example,
>   by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the
>   list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see
>   InnerException for more details.

Now I've even tried adding all the "Service Known Type" attributes to my service interface, with no luck:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IServerProxy
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool Connect(long FBUID, string SecretKey);

        [OperationContract]
        [ServiceKnownType(typeof(IDictionary<byte, Hashtable>))]
        [ServiceKnownType(typeof(IDictionary<Hashtable, Hashtable>))]
        [ServiceKnownType(typeof(IDictionary<object, object>))]
        [ServiceKnownType(typeof(IDictionary<object, IDictionary<object, object>>))]
        List<QueuedMessage> Update(long FBUID, string SecretKey);
    }
```

But to be perfectly honest, I've used that tag blindly without full understanding of what it does and how (and if) it can be used to help me.

So, anyone has any idea what I should do?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try `[ServiceKnownType(typeof(HashTable))]`? more generally, though, IMO sending a hashtable here is a bad practice. "Existing code requirements" aren't a magic wand that makes impossible stuff work - better idea is to transfer it in a *simple way that works*, and then munge it to what the other end needs **after** that.

Comment: Well let me take a step back and explain what I'm trying to do - we're working with an old, existing socket framework, that doesn't support HTTP tunneling, and I want to wrap the entire process inside a web service for users who have firewalls only allow traffic on port 80. So one of the requirements of this framework is to use hashtables, removing them might enable our WCF service, but it would also break our TCP service.

Comment: Your TCP service supports bytes; only bytes; not sure how hashtable is related there... if the issue is that you were using `BinaryFormatter` before (which, btw, is not necessarily a safe choice), then maybe use `NetDataContractSerializer` *here* (instead of `DataContractSerializer`; googling will show you how to configure this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500870/serialize-generic-type-over-wcf-service/10501162#10501162) regarding generics in wcf. Generics are not possible in a SOA situation. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554205/sending-a-hashtable-to-a-webservice) proposes an alterative solution. Hope this helps